# NodeJS: Is is possible to show the stack trace of a calling async function?

Tags: node.js, debugging, trace

Most APIs in node libraries are asynchronous by design. When an exception is thrown in a callback the stacktrace shows only the call stack starting at process._tickCallback.

I wonder whether there is a trick to show also the stack trace of the function that trigerred the _tickCallback.

Comment: [Here is a method you can use (Link to a Gihub Gist).](https://gist.github.com/lll000111/3d6a53da4d53beb909189793c7631ba6) Disadvantages: A few additional lines of code - you have to wrap all async. function calls with `try/catch` (you can also use `promise.catch(...)`). Then you create a new `Error` object and add its `stack` property to the existing stack. If done for ALL async. function calls you end up with a full stack trace. The speed disadvantage (stack trace creation is expensive) should not matter for async. functions (pls. don't use exceptions for normal control flow).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Node.js 12, Async Stack Traces come out of the box with flag

```
--async-stack-traces
```

Node.js Foundation release post - https://medium.com/@nodejs/introducing-node-js-12-76c41a1b3f3f

Answer (score 7):

In node 8 version appeared `async_hooks`

[trace](https://github.com/AndreasMadsen/trace) uses this for async stack traces

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at long stacktraces to see if it fits your needs.
The module is called stackups. All you do is install it:

```
npm install --save stackup
```

and then require it:

```
require('stackup');
```

More info here: https://github.com/groundwater/node-stackup